# How to add "subject directory attributes" to a certificate using Python?

Tags: pyopenssl

I have tried `crypto.X509Extension('subjectDirAttrs', ...)`, but Python gave the error like 'unknown extension'.

Can anyone give a solution? Thanks in advance!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from OpenSSL import crypto

newSubject=crypto.X509Name(crypto.X509().get_subject())

newSubject.C='US'
newSubject.ST='California'
newSubject.O='University of California, Davis'
newSubject.OU='Computer Science, UCDavis'
newSubject.CN='www.cs.ucdavis.edu'

newCert=crypto.X509()
newCert.set_version(2)
newCert.set_serial_number(2016120711)
newCert.set_notBefore('20161207125959Z')
newCert.set_notAfter('20171207125959Z')
newCert.set_issuer(newSubject)
newCert.set_subject(newSubject)

pkObject=crypto.PKey()
pkObject.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA,2048) 

newCert.set_pubkey(pkObject)

newExt=crypto.X509Extension('basicConstraints', True, 'CA:true')
newCert.add_extensions([newExt])

newExt=crypto.X509Extension('subjectDirAttrs', True, 'something')
newCert.add_extensions([newExt])


newCert.sign(pkObject,'sha256')
with open('ask_stackoverflow.pem','w') as f:
    f.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,newCert))
```

I have tried 'subjectDirectoryAttributes' and 'subjectDirAttrs', but neither of them can work.

Comment: first make sure that you have the `crypto` module installed locally and also that it is imported in the current file. This seems to be an error with missing system dependency/library. Also consider adding the full code/example code to reproduce the problem in order to better troubleshoot

Comment: I have installed PyOpenSSL v16.1.0 and have imported crypto from OpenSSL. My full code is listed as follows:  @DaGhostman Dimitrov, @ Procrastinatus Maximus

Comment: OpenSSL does not support Subject Directory Attributes extension out of the box. Also see [How to parse Subject Directory Attributes Extension?](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-May/005811.html) on the OpenSSL users mailing list.